# Ruby: How to check for negative zero

Tags: ruby

How can I find out if a `Float` value is a negative zero (and not a positive one)?

Unfortunately:

```
-0.0 == 0.0   # => true
-0.0 === 0.0  # => true
```

My initial solution works but is ugly:

```
x.to_s == '-0.0'
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409102/how-do-i-check-if-a-zero-is-positive-or-negative), I found

```
x == 0 and 1 / x < 0
```

Is there a better, more Ruby-like way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `angle` method (and it's aliases `arg` and `phase`) returns zero for positive floats and Pi for negatives.

```
p 0.0.angle  #=> 0
p -0.0.angle #=> 3.141592653589793
```

Answer (score 7):

Ruby's `BigDecimal` class has a `sign` method that produces the correct result for negative zero. You can convert a `Float` to a `BigDecimal` with the `to_d` method if you `require 'bigdecimal/util'`.

```
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'bigdecimal/util'

0.0.to_d.sign
#=> 1

-0.0.to_d.sign
#=> -1
```

Combine this with `zero?` and you're good to go:

```
def negative_zero?(x)
  x.zero? && x.to_d.sign == -1
end

negative_zero?(0.0)
#=> false

negative_zero?(-0.0)
#=> true
```

Comment: So many new things.. I still need to learn.. :) Thanks for showing this.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby the `Float` equality operator for `-0.0` and `0.0` returns true, as per [ordinary arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero).

However if you convert the two floats to bytes using little-endian or big-endian byte order, you'll see they do not in fact match.

```
[-0.0].pack('E')
#=> "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80"

[0.0].pack('E')
#=> "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"

[-0.0].pack('E') == [0.0].pack('E')
#=> false
```

Answer (score 2):

If your purpose is to prevent "negative zero", then this is how [rails does it](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1414910502d6d286f7f44b1a24d546f562804f07/activesupport/lib/active_support/number_helper/rounding_helper.rb#L31):

```
number = number.abs if number.zero?
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause ruby determines them as the same object the only way to detect it by "-" sign after string conversion, as you described: `-0.0.to_s.start_with?('-')`.