# grails how to check Double negative zero

Tags: grails

I googled the answer.  They said use Double.compare().
It does not work.

```
Double.compare(-0d, 0d) < 0
```

This gives me false.  Should be true.

Math.signum() does not work with -0d.  The document says it will give me back -0d.

On the other hand, if I have a formula that calculate the value to be -zero, compare gives me a different answer.

```
def xyz = -0d
Double.compare(xyz, 0d) < 0 will give me false
```

```
def xyz = 0d * -1d
Double.compare(xyz, 0d) < 0 will give me true
```

Is this a bug in Grails?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409102/how-do-i-check-if-a-zero-is-positive-or-negative.

Comment: "Is this a bug in Grails?" - It is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you expect comparing `-0d` with `0d` to be not equal?

```
Double.compare(-0d, 0d) < 0// returns false
```

cause

```
Double.compare(-0d, 0d) == 0 //returns true
```

Comment: Let me try Math.signum() again.  I may have read the document wrong.  signum() may work.  compare() is just not reliable to me.  Worst case scenario is to turn the number into a string and to look for the minus letter in the first letter.